# React: refactoring multiple form inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm in the process of learning React. I was doing one of the refractor exercises as below:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

    import "./App.css";

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        form: {
          firstName: "",
          lastName: "",
          email: "",
          password: ""
        }
      };

      handleFirstNameChange = e => {
        this.setState({
          form: {
            firstName: e.target.value
          }
        });
      };

      handleLastNameChange = e => {
        this.setState({
          form: {
            lastName: e.target.value
          }
        });
      };

      handleEmailChange = e => {
        this.setState({
          form: {
            email: e.target.value
          }
        });
      };

      handlePasswordChange = e => {
        this.setState({
          form: {
            password: e.target.value
          }
        });
      };

      validateForm = () => {
        const formInputs = ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password"];

        for (let i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
          const inputName = formInputs[i];

          if (!this.state.form[inputName].length) {
            return false;
          }
        }

        return true;
      };

      handleSubmit = () => {
        if (this.validateForm()) {
          console.log("Success!");
        } else {
          console.log("Failure!");
        }
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
          >
            <form
              className="Form"
              onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.handleSubmit();
              }}
            >
              <input name="firstName" onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} />
              <input name="lastName" onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} />
              <input name="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} />
              <input name="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
              <button className="no-padding">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

and I refactored it to :

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  import "./App.css";

  class App extends Component {
    state = {
      form: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };

    handleChange = e => {
      this.setState({
        form: {
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
      });
    };

    validateForm = () => {
      const formInputs = ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password"];

      for (let i = 0; i < formInputs.length; i++) {
        const inputName = formInputs[i];

        if (!this.state.form[inputName].length) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    };

    handleSubmit = () => {
      if (this.validateForm()) {
        console.log("Success!");
      } else {
        console.log("Failure!");
      }
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <form
            className="Form"
            onSubmit={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              this.handleSubmit();
            }}
          >
            <input name="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input name="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <input name="password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <button className="no-padding">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

For some reason, I got an error when I submit my form -

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I was wondering what did I do wrong in my code?

Also is there a better way to refactor the code even more?

Comment: its because state variable name is `email` and in array you have defined: `emailAddress`. Error is because `this.state.form.emailAddress` will be `undefined`, and that why *Cannot read property 'length' of undefined*.

Comment: @MayankShukla I changed 'emailAddress' to 'email' in my array and still getting the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are updating the state in wrong way, during update each time you are deleting all other key value pairs from the form array, instead of just updating any one key value.

Update it like this:

```
handleChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    form: {

      // all other key value pairs of form object
      ...prevState.form,

      // update this one specifically
      [name]: value
    }
  }));
};
```

Check this snippet to get the better idea:

```js
let obj1 = { a:1, b:2 };
let obj2 = { a:1, b:2 };

let temp = 'a';

obj1 = { [temp]: 10 };

obj2 = { ...obj2, [temp]: 10 };

console.log('obj1', obj1);
console.log('obj2', obj2);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code snippet. There was two mistakes one is in the handleChange event setting the right values in the state. Email address state property name being different at two places

https://codesandbox.io/s/5kz5wko31k